# JavaScript insertAfter and insertBefore

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am playing around with the JavaScript functions `insertAfter` and `insertBefore`, however I am trying to `insertAfter` and `insertBefore` two elements.

For instance, consider the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Item 1
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="moveUpDown">
                    <div class="up">
                    </div>
                    <div class="down">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Item 2
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="moveUpDown">
                    <div class="up">
                    </div>
                    <div class="down">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Then I have this JavaScript code snippet:

```
var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
if ($(this).is(".up")) {
    row.insertBefore(row.prev());
} else {
    row.insertAfter(row.next());
}
```

Basically when the `Up` class is called, the previous row is moved up and when the `Down` class is called, the current row is moved down one row.

What I want to do, is move the rows Up/Down 2 rows... meaning something like `row.prev().prev()` or `row.next().next()` however this does not seem to work.

Is there an easy way around this?

Would appreciate any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to go up

```
row.prev().prev().before(row)
```

to go down

```
row.next().next().after(row)
```

obviously the tr must exist prev/next have to exist

NB you are caching row as the first tr element so row is changing every time the first tr element change

listen to event

```
$("table").on("click","tr > td > span.moveup", function() {
  var row = $(this).parent().parent();

 if (row.prev().prev().get(0)) row.prev().prev().before(row)

})
```

Comment: I put this code:     $(document).on("click", "tr > td div.up", function() {
        var row = $(this).parent().parent();

        if (row.prev().prev().get(0)) row.prev().prev().before(row)

    }) ... however the rows arent moving?

Comment: @Kelish your div is nested in another one ! you need to add one more parent & it's working : http://jsfiddle.net/4ZwWv/

Comment: @Kelish fiddle is gone sorry anyway you have to add a parent() to get a tr in row & that is it

Comment: Thanks mikakun, makes a lot of sense now!